# You can see the real me If you just try hard a bit, what am I?

Tags: riddle

Hello I am new and this is my first riddle, sorry for the bad english!

You should guess what am I

I'll tell you Mark is my name

There are many friends of mine

but I'm the easier to tame

I won't talk so much about my head

I'll just let you know that without it I wouldn't be dead

Let's talk about my body

I don't have any legs, arms or horns

but it can have many shapes or forms

I am all over the world

You can find me if you search far and wide

Try to look near the spider's lair

You can see the real me

If you just try hard a bit

What is **it**?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Your English seems fine to me. c:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is it HTML?

I'll finish explaining later if it is :D
I'll tell you Mark is my name

> HT**Mark**upL

There are many friends of mine

> Basic web language

but I'm the easier to tame

> Easy to use and no errors shown on screen even when code isn't right

I won't talk so much about my head

> Head is part of html script you don't see without looking at the code

I'll just let you know that without it I wouldn't be dead

> Html works without head

Let's talk about my body

> body is an important part of HTML code

I don't have any legs, arms or horns

Don't know for this one yet

but it can have many shapes or forms

> Html changes with CSS?

I am all over the world

> On the internet

You can find me if you search far and wide

> World Wide

Try to look near the spider's lair

> The web

You can see the real me

If you just try hard a bit

> Source code examined with with browser

Comment: legs, arms and horns are not valid HTML tags

Comment: @SeanC: The riddle says "I don't have any legs, arms or horns".

Comment: @paolo, exactly. IdiotStyle couldn't think of a reason for that line in his answer.

Comment: This is the right answer! Good job!